# Chrome Browser utilizing 100% NVIDIA GPU

Tags: video-streaming, gpu, nvidia, video-processing, ant-media-server-sdk

We are trying to build a video wall with webrtc streams from Ant Media Server and facing issues on the client workstation that is housing this video application.

We have a chrome browser based video wall with matrix system of video streams being displayed. Below is the system config ,

- OS -- Windows 10 Pro 64bit
- CPU -- Intel i7 4 core
- GPU 1 -- Intel HD graphics 4600 series
- GPU 2 -- Nvidia Quadro K2100M
- Display Resolution --  1920 x 1080

When I run the browser application in default graphic settings I see the video decode is happening as expected on the Intel GPU card and it takes not more than 50% for 30 video streams but when I set chrome to run on high performance and run the application the Nvidia card within a minute reaches 100% utilization.

I am a little confused with this behavior , generally the dedicated GPU's perform better than the integrated one's. What should i deduce from this ? that the current nvidia card is useless in video decode and change it or is there any other settings that i need to do ?

Let me know if any additional information is required.

Comment: "within a minute"  I've had all sort of power throttling issues before.  Not sure that's what's happening here, but something to look into.  Also, how are you measuring the utilization?  Are you sure it's accurately measuring what you expect?  What codecs are you using?  Are you sure they're being decoded where you expect?  chrome://media-internals/ might be helpful here.

Comment: I am looking at the Task Manager under the performance tab and i can see the utilization going upto 100%. Also i can see the video frames dropping heavily. The camera's use H.264 for video encoding.